# Which gets more interactive: QR code or shorten link?

Tags: hyperlinks, interactive-ui, qr-codes

I am making a poster and I would like to add a document so that anyone who is interested can see further details. At first, I thought that using a QR code would make it look cooler, but after reading a number of comments on the internet, such as [this one on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Entrepreneur/comments/1q659b/what_do_you_think_about_qr_codes_on_business_cards/cda70nq), I think that it will soon be abandoned (relevant section quoted below).

> I sent out over 50,000 mailings with QR codes on them to Real Estate
>   agents. (They claim to love QR codes)
>
> I did this to prove to my CEO that QR codes would be awesome.
>
> 3 people scanned them.
>
> We don't talk about QR codes any more.

However, I need to add a link, and it seems that the only other way is by shortening it. This is what it could look like:

> To view the full document, scan this QR code:

or

> To view the full document, go to this link: bit.ly/doc_name

Which one do you think would attract more interest?

**More info**: I work in a science field and I'm making a poster for a conference to introduce/advertise my work to others. I want to add a link to my paperwork for interested viewers, but I don't have a company website (my work is stored on Google Drive). Also, I will have told the viewers what the content is, so I don't think they will be worried by it.

As PhillipW suggests, it is better to have my own website, which I will do, but in the near future as I don't have time for that now.

Comment: Why not use a full URL? Just set up a 'vanity' URL for the promotion. Something like `www.your-company.com/superpromotion` and have that as a 301 redirect to the actual full URL. The issue with short URLs and QR codes is that the user has no idea what it is they're clicking on. And that's a security risk (whether you intend it to be or not).

Comment: I agree with @JonW.  The other problem with short URLs is they aren't meant to be human readable.  They will be hard to remember/write down.  With a full URL it is, and the user may also remember your website URL and just go to the home page.

Comment: I'd suggest the vanity URL as an answer.

Comment: I'd probably just register my own domain for the occasion (often less that £10) and set up a redirect from it the posting on google docs.

Answer (score 5):

For starters, I dont agree with your response that  you don't have time to set up a domain name. It takes like 10 minutes and would be a worthwhile investment on your behalf since the domain name would be so much more easier to remember rather than a bitly link or even a [tr.im](https://tr.im/) link.

My suggestion would be **have a combination of both a QR code and and the URL** (provide the URL below the QR code). Here is an example

[image]

This would handle the case in case the person doesn't have a QR code reader and he can then enter the URL below it and in a best case scenario he can just use the URL. The presence of the URL also enables users to be able to note it down as needed.

Comment: This answer has become something of a standard 9 years later. I would vote for this to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the scenario i guess you can go for a full stretch URL as a few have suggested provided you make your URLs as short and as readable as possible so that they are easy to read and understand and also mean no threat.